# Guess function in Flash

Tags: actionscript, flash-8

I am stuck with my Flash game. I need the syntax in action script for the below logic. My game is pretty large and complex to explain and I will explain you a quick simple example.

I have 2 buttons. First one is button1 and the Second one is button2. When I click on button1 there should be a guess and response your guess is right or wrong. It's just a random guess function to say my guess is right or wrong. There are only 2 buttons either button1 or button2 should be correct as per instance.

Can anyone tell me the syntax in action script to check the random guess?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What part are you struggling with? The question to show up? To check which button has been clicked? The decision if the answer is right or wrong?

Comment: Yes, the clicked button is right decision or not. That's it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly this should work:

```
button1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, randomGuess); // Event Listeners
button2.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, randomGuess);

function randomGuess(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    var guess:Boolean =  Boolean(Math.round(Math.random()));//Random Value
    var input:Boolean; // To define input value
    if (event.target.name == "button1"){
        input = true; // set input value
    }
    else if (event.target.name == "button2"){
        input = false;
    }

    if (guess == input){ //compare input value to the random value
        trace("You guessed it.");
    }
    else{
        trace("You didnt guess it.");
    }
```

}